# Listview width error, but it is wrap content

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

i have this rot to listview:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="0">

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:text="@string/brand"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_margin="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvBrand"
                android:text="MarcaTV"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:layout_margin="1dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:text="@string/type"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_margin="1dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvType"
                android:text="TipoTV"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:layout_margin="1dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:text="@string/model"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_margin="1dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvModel"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:text="ModelTV"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:layout_margin="1dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:text="@string/color"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_margin="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvColor"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:text="ColorTV"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:layout_margin="1dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:text="@string/hand"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_margin="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvHand"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:text="ManoTV"
                android:layout_margin="1dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="32dp"
                    android:text="10,99"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="32dp"
                    android:text="€"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:id="@+id/tvQty"
                    android:textSize="32dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Unidades"
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This must be show like this:

[image]

But it shows like this:

[image]

I dont know why have this margin on bottom...!!

Comment: android:padding="8dp" ...

Comment: no, i delete this and not change.

Comment: Try add `maginBottom = 0dp`.

Comment: @FerzinhaFil in witch item?

Comment: Where you are using the margins. Try.